# Why Connect Timeout and Response Timeout not working in JMeter?

Tags: load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a very simple thread group that simulates 100 users hitting www.google.com. I notice that Connect Timeout and Response Timeout are not working as expected.

In the HTTP Request, I've specified Connect Timeout to be 5ms and Response Timeout 7ms.

[image]

But in the results, I see requests failing that shouldn't have failed. In this case, Connect Time is 3ms and Response Time= Load - Connect = 9-3= 6ms.

[image]

Can some kind soul please show me what is going on here? Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: is it a JMeter (tool you are using)

Comment: @VishalAkkalkote yes it is

Answer (score 0):

The Jmeter result is correct here. It should fail because you have given expected time of connect as 5 and response as 7. And the load time of the request is  9 seconds- Which is greater than your provided expected value.

To make it simple. Jmeter default timeout is 21 seconds. If you don't provide any value in timeout, the requests will fail automatically when its exceeds 21 seconds of load time.
In your case, since you already provided the expected timeout value and since all of the requests taking more this value, its failing which is normal. 
Try increase the connect and response time and try